# Bot reacting to emojis

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I got my code and it works just as I want it to. the message pops up changes everything, it's perfect.
Now I want to add so the bot knows when I react to its message and then does something else. What I mean is: bot sends a message with reacts, and whenever some user clicks the reaction something happens, but I have no idea how to do that.

I've tried many things like `if (reaction.emoji.name === ':bomb:')`, but multiple errors popped out and I didn't know how to fix that. Here's the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
var lastbuffer;
lastbuffer = 0;
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');

});
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}start`)){
    message.delete()
    setInterval(function(){
      lastbuffer++;
      const Buffer = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#8300FF')
      .setTitle("**It's time to check buffers!**")
      .setDescription("**It's been **" + "`" + lastbuffer + " Hour" + "`" + "** since last buffercheck, <@&675688526460878848>**." + " **Check now!**")
      .setThumbnail('https://art.pixilart.com/88534e2f28b65a4.png')
      .setFooter('WEEEEEWOOOOO')
      .setTimestamp();
      client.channels.cache.get("700296799482675230").send(Buffer).then(msg => {
        msg.react('✅');
        msg.react('');
        msg.delete({timeout: 4000})
      });
    }, 5000)
  }
}); 

client.login(token);
```

Comment: "Multiple errors popped out" sounds interesting. Can you share even one of these errors?

Comment: can’t tell you now, i managed to fix that now

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use a [`ReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector) using the [`createReactionCollector()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) method.

You can follow [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) to under `ReactionCollector`s better

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Additionally, please avoid external links as the only source for a solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [reaction collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors).

```js
client.channels.cache.get("700296799482675230").send(Buffer).then(async msg => {
  // I'm using await here so the emojis react in the right order
  await msg.react('✅');
  await msg.react('');
  msg.awaitReactions(
    // Discord.js v12:
    /* ({emoji}, user) => ['✅', ''].includes(emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id,
    {max: 1, time: 4000, errors: ['time']} */
    // Discord.js v13:
    {
      // only collect the emojis from the message author
      filter: ({emoji}, user) => ['✅', ''].includes(emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id,
      // stop collecting when 1 reaction has been collected or throw an error after 4 seconds
      max: 1,
      time: 4000,
      errors: ['time']
    }
  )
    .then(collected => {
      const reaction = collected.first()
      // do something
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // I'm assuming you want to delete the message if the user didn't react in time
      msg.delete()
    })
```

What this code does:

- Sends the embed (`Buffer`) to the channel with the id 700296799482675230
- Reacts with the ✅ and then the  emojis on the message with the embed
- Waits for a ✅ or  reaction from the author of the original message

  - If the user reacts within 4 seconds, runs the `// do something` part
  - If the user does not react within 4 seconds, deletes the message with the embed

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it